# Trouble on parsing JSON data within a Python script

Tags: python, json, parsing, error-handling

I wrote my first Python script (note: I am new to Python) and I am trying to parse some JSON string in order to retrieve a value related to a particular JSON key but I am in trouble.

In my `script.py` file I have the following:

```
data = '{ "key1": "152", "key2": "da8fb07ace5512", "key3": "cfed379e13aebc" }'
data_decoded = json.load(data)
data["key1"]
```

When I run the above script with the command `python script.py` then I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/script.py", line 2, in <module>
    data_decoded = json.load(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 274, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

How can I solve the problem? I expect that the returned value is `152`.

---

**UPDATE** (after commenting)

If I use `loads()` then I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/script.py", line 3, in <module>
    data["key1"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

I don't care if it is a string or a integer. I would like just to retrieve the value.

Comment: Try using ``json.loads()`` instead of ``json.load()`` - parses a string instead of a file stream.

Comment: "I don't care if it is a string or a integer." - it's not a value that is a string or integer. You see the "indices" word in the error message? You are supposed to **read and understand** error messages, that's why they are here. They help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json.load` expects a <strike>filename</strike> file-like object.  You want to use `json.loads` which loads from a string.

See also: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Edit:  Try `data_decoded['152']`.  You're still trying to access `data`, the JSON string

Comment: `json.load` does not expect a filename. It takes a file object.

Answer (score 1):

For strings, you have to use `json.loads()`, not `json.load()`, because `load` is for files and file-like objects.

Comment: @Backo Now read your code **carefully.** What are you indexing? What **should** you be indexing instead?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @Backo I mean you should read your code and think about what it is doing. `data["key1"]` doesn't make sense. `data_decoded["key1"]` does. Please show a bit of effort debugging your **own** code, especially since this is a trivial error.

Answer (score 0):

You are already declaring your dictionary object, just take it out of quotation marks:

```
data = { "key1": "152", "key2": "da8fb07ace5512", "key3": "cfed379e13aebc" }
```

Because you already have a dictionary there is no need to do a json function, just simply reference the data:

```
data['key1']
```

However, if I am misunderstanding your question and you are passing in the data as a json, python will recognize it as a string and you need to use a json.loads function on the data:

Note that after you issue the data_decoded = json.loads(data), your dictionary object is no longer data, it is actually now data_decoded.  Did you try:

```
data_decoded['key1']
```

???

Good luck!